How to properly configure proxy for scrapy-splash?
I am trying to configure scrapy-splash to work through a proxy, but the result is always the 504 error HTTP code:
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (504) <GET https://www.website.com via http://localhost:8050/execute> (referer: None)
INFO:scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror:Ignoring response <504 https://www.website.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed

This is my basic setup:
lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
    splash:go(args.url)

    local num_scrolls = 3
    local wait_after_scroll = 1.0

    local scroll_to = splash:jsfunc("window.scrollTo")
    local get_body_height = splash:jsfunc(
        "function() { return document.body.scrollHeight; }"
    )

    -- scroll to the end for "num_scrolls" time
    for _ = 1, num_scrolls do
        scroll_to(0, get_body_height())
        splash:wait(wait_after_scroll)
    end       
        
    return splash:html()
end
...
def start_requests(self):
  yield SplashRequest(URL,
                      callback=self.parse,
                      endpoint="execute",
                      args={
                           'wait': 5,
                           'lua_source': lua_script,
                           'proxy': API_PROXY
                      })

I also tried a version where I specified the proxy in the lua script:
lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
    splash:on_request(function(request)
        request:set_proxy("http://proxy.server.com:8001")
        request:set_header("Proxy-Authorization", "Basic " .. splash:base64_encode("username:password"))
    end)
    
    splash:go(args.url)
    splash:wait(1)  -- Wait for page to load (customize wait time as needed)
    
    return splash:html()
end
"""

Yet the result was the same - 504 error code.
I am running this script on my localhost (OSX) - the splash server is ran via docker (docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash).
I saw on StackOverflow a few similar questions, but only with a few answers and the answers unfortunately didn't help me to make this work.
If I remove the proxy from the query, the script is running and is fetching data. How to properly configure scrapy-splash with the proxy?

Your args to request:set_proxy are wrong.
